# how to trace a curve through a grid and find all cells that are intersected

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-methods

I have a rectangular grid with cell centers defined by y-coordinates (array `y`) and x-coordinates (array `x`). Interfaces are defined similarly in arrays `xi` and `yi`. Then there is a function f(x) that goes through that grid. This *could* be a simple line but can also be a more complicated curve (hence Bresenham's Algorithm might not work).

Is there a simple (python) way to find all the grid cells that are intersected by the curve?

Comment: How is `f(x)` given? A formula? A list of `(x, y)` pairs?

Comment: Could be either way. Let's for now say is an array with a y value for every entry in the x array. The curve is then a nonlinear interpolation between those values.

Comment: Are the x's are ordered by order of appearance on the curve? If so, interpolate y values for the x's between each adjacent pair then round them to the nearest y coordinate. You can improve performance according to the way you interpolate the function values. If it's a straight line, use Bressenham, if another function than you night use a similar method.

Comment: @JohnSmith did the linked question answer your problem?

Comment: IMO the linked question does not answer this question.

Comment: @Amnon - The linked question is an answer to a well specified and simpler version of this question, and even there the answer isn't "simple". So it's not a literal duplicate, but if one goes literal with this question: "Is there a simple...", the answer is just "No". If you or others think it's reasonable to search out ways to interpret this question, and hone down the generalities, and work out how "simple" the answer needs to be for the OP, I'm happy to vote to reopen. Personally, I think the OP should consider this question in light of the others and ask one that's better defined.